# do I need to setup my XMPP server if to use it for an real-time chat app running on iPhone and Android?

Tags: xmpp, chat, real-time

Is there a public XMPP server available either free or commercial with good quality? Or we need to set it up ourselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a publicly available XMPP server for free during your test/development phases. http://xmpp.net will give you a list of freely available Jabber servers. However, once you have your application running into production and specially at some scale, it's not recommended to use a 3rd party freely available server for your application.

Alternately, if all you care about is adding real-time chat inside your application and not about XMPP or any other underlying protocol, i would recommend checking [this answer out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893001/client-server-constant-communication-php/11912911#11912911).