# XMPP Android Implementation Guide

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, chat, openshift

Guys I am new to XMPP functionality and I am reading topics on GCM with XMPP, how to implement chat functionality using xmpp.
Basically I am doing proof of concept so that i will be comfortable before i start.  I have the below infrastructure to host my android app:

1. Java backend + MySQL database.
2. OpenShift cloud platform to host my backend application.
3. Google cloud messaging to send notifications to client devices.

Right now, I am totally lost.
How to start with XMPP,  i have got couple of links

[XMPP implementation using QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample)

[GCM XMPP implementation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs)

where i got basic knowledge, but i want to  use XMPP with my existing app, which is running on OpenShift.

My questions are:

1- Is there any available APIs for XMPP that i can integrate with my app (so that i can decrease my development time) ?

2- Do i need separate server for XMPP for chat functionality?

Comment: You should use XMPP to do chat functionality, it is more efficient than HTTP. On android the XMPP is handled for you. On your server you can use the Smack Java XMPP library to connect to CCS.

Comment: @ArthurThompson, i am not getting samples to implement my xmpp server side and i am checking feasibility of having xmpp server side code on openshift, any document related to this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following github project will help you.everything is there for a simple xmpp chat app
https://github.com/jerrya/AndroidSmackSample

Comment: how to connect xmpp server.. it doesnt say anything about xmpp server setup

Comment: ya.its xmpp client app.

Comment: i have installed above xmpp client app, how to setup server, since it connects to local host?

Comment: I am not sure. I haven't done the server side. may be this could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994356/do-i-need-to-setup-my-xmpp-server-if-to-use-it-for-an-real-time-chat-app-running

Answer (score 0):

> My questions are:
>   1- Is there any available APIs for XMPP that i can integrate with my app (so that i can decrease my development time) ?
>   2- Do i need separate server for XMPP for chat functionality?

You will need your separate XMPP integrated server for both options. You can choose any one practice to integrate XMPP real-time chat in your app.

1. Using that server's base URL, you can use [REST API Plugin](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/1.3.9/restAPI/readme.html).
2. Integrate XMPP chat in your app using [Smack](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack) provided by [Ignite Realtime](https://www.igniterealtime.org/).

I have uploaded sample Android app's source code [here](https://github.com/KaluKhan/ChatYoXMPP-Android).